# Biblatex after partial bibliograph sets markers to [0]

Tags: biblatex

I'm writing an application, and they want me to put my own relevant papers at one point in the document, without numbers, and then a normal bibliography at another point.
I've looked through old answers here about multiple bibliographies, and made it work more or less.
But one thing is failing me, right now all papers that are cited after the section with my own relevant papers get a marker [0]. They still show up in the bibliography with a normal number though.

My minimal working example is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[pdfauthor="Me",pdftitle="generic title",breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[sorting=none,giveninits=true, uniquename=init,doi=false,isbn=false,backend=biber,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{mythings.bib}
@MISC{me,
  author  = {Me Myself},
  title   = {Some Title},
  year    = 2001
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{otherthings.bib}
@MISC{se1,
  author  = {Someone Else},
  title   = {Some Title},
  year    = 1001
  }
@MISC{se2,
  author  = {Someone Else},
  title   = {Some Title II- this is different},
  year    = 1001
  }
@MISC{se3,
  author  = {Someone Else},
  title   = {Some Title III},
  year    = 1001
  }
\end{filecontents}


\defbibenvironment{mypubs}
 {\list
     {$\bullet$}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}


\def\printbib#1{
\newrefcontext[sorting=none]
\printbibliography[category=#1,heading=#1,omitnumbers=false]}
\def\printPRbib#1{
\newrefcontext[sorting=ynt]
\printbibliography[env=mypubs,category=#1,heading=#1,omitnumbers=true]}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont\fontsize{11}{13.4}\sffamily}

\def\makebibsubsubsec#1#2{\DeclareBibliographyCategory{#1}\defbibheading{#1}{\subsubsection{#2}}}

\def\makebibsubsec#1#2{\DeclareBibliographyCategory{#1}\defbibheading{#1}{\subsection{#2}}}

\makebibsubsubsec{prpub}{Articles}
\makebibsubsec{published}{Articles }
\makebibsubsec{other}{Other publications}


\addbibresource{mythings.bib}
\addbibresource{otherthings.bib}

\addtocategory{other}{se2}
\addtocategory{published}{se1,se3}
\addtocategory{prpub}{me}
\nocite{me}

\begin{document}
Test \cite{se2} and another \cite{se3}

\printPRbib{prpub}

And now somemore text and another citation~\cite{se1}
\printbib{published}
\printbib{other}
\end{document}
```

**Edited**
My output is
[image: Output of the compilation]

I'm using biber 2.4 and biblatex version 3.4

Comment: Can you add a picture of the output you get, please? After a compilation circle of LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pvl0.png What version of `biblatex` and Biber do you have?

Comment: You should also fix the title of your question, you're using biblatex + biber, so the bibtex in the title is confusing

Comment: Anyway, I would probably use a `refcontext` environment in `\printPRbib` to avoid the context leaking out, that way you won't need a `\newrefcontext` later: `\def\printbib#1{%
  \printbibliography[category=#1,heading=#1,omitnumbers=false]}
\def\printPRbib#1{%
  \begin{refcontext}[sorting=ynt]
  \printbibliography[env=mypubs,category=#1,heading=#1,omitnumbers=true]
  \end{refcontext}}` (modulo line breaks). And finally: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Thanks, I added the information in the question and adjusted the title. I just somehow still think of it as bibtex, that's why I wrote that.

Comment: Your `biblatex` and Biber versions are a bit dated by today's standards, currently we have 3.11 and 2.11 out. It's not impossible that there was a bug that would have caused this behaviour in older versions. But it must have been fixed by now since I get the correct output. Does using the environment form as suggested in my comment above help?

Comment: Hi Moewe, I added the \begin{refcontext} and that seems to have fixed the issue.
The versions are a bit older because they are what I got from the Ubuntu repositories, so I figured it should be good enough.

Comment: You might be interested in the `biblatex-publist` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current `biblatex` 3.11, Biber 2.11 I get

[image: The relevant problematic line reads "And now somemore text and another citation [2]" now instead of "And now somemore text and another citation [0]" as in the OP]

from your MWE. So this must be a bug in version 3.4 of `biblatex` that has since been fixed. My money is on https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/396 for the time being, but I can't be sure.

As suggested in the comments you should consider using a `refcontext` environment for your own publications. That way you don't influence the other references in the document - you won't need the `\newrefcontext[sorting=none]`.

The following MWE (with `\newcommand` instead of `\def`) should work

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[pdfauthor="Me",pdftitle="generic title",breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[sorting=none,giveninits=true, uniquename=init,doi=false,isbn=false,backend=biber,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{mythings.bib}
@MISC{me,
  author  = {Me Myself},
  title   = {Some Title},
  year    = 2001
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{otherthings.bib}
@MISC{se1,
  author  = {Someone Else},
  title   = {Some Title},
  year    = 1001
  }
@MISC{se2,
  author  = {Someone Else},
  title   = {Some Title II- this is different},
  year    = 1001
  }
@MISC{se3,
  author  = {Someone Else},
  title   = {Some Title III},
  year    = 1001
  }
\end{filecontents}


\defbibenvironment{mypubs}
  {\list
     {$\bullet$}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}


\newcommand*{\printbib}[1]{%
  \printbibliography[category=#1,heading=#1,omitnumbers=false]}
\newcommand*{\printPRbib}[1]{%
  \begin{refcontext}[sorting=ynt]
  \printbibliography[env=mypubs,category=#1,heading=#1,omitnumbers=true]
  \end{refcontext}}

\newcommand*{\makebibsubsubsec}[2]{%
  \DeclareBibliographyCategory{#1}%
  \defbibheading{#1}{\subsubsection{#2}}}

\newcommand*{\makebibsubsec}[2]{%
  \DeclareBibliographyCategory{#1}%
  \defbibheading{#1}{\subsection{#2}}}

\makebibsubsubsec{prpub}{Articles}
\makebibsubsec{published}{Articles}
\makebibsubsec{other}{Other publications}

\addbibresource{mythings.bib}
\addbibresource{otherthings.bib}

\addtocategory{other}{se2}
\addtocategory{published}{se1,se3}
\addtocategory{prpub}{me}
\nocite{me}

\begin{document}
Test \cite{se2} and another \cite{se3}

\printPRbib{prpub}

And now somemore text and another citation~\cite{se1}
\printbib{published}
\printbib{other}
\end{document}
```

[image: Again the relevant problematic line reads "And now somemore text and another citation [2]" now instead of "And now somemore text and another citation [0]" as in the OP.]